# displaying menu just by using css and html

Tags: html, css, web, navigation

I am learning web development,html css kind of things.I wrote following css to best of my knowledge, but when I view it in browser it does not comes as I expect it to come.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>Jenware | Personalized Gifts</title>
<style type="text/css">

p.float {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0px;
  background: #CCC;
 }

p {
 border: 1px solid red;
}

ul  {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

ul li {
float: left;
}

ul li a {
display: block;
/* more styles */
}


</style>

</head>

<body>
<ul> 
  <li><a href="#">Serif</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sans-serif</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Script</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Display</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Dingbats</a></li>
</ul>


</body>
</html>
```

I expect boxes i.e.  the unordered list is transformed into a tab-like menu using CSS alone and no images.

Displaying some thing like

[image]

but this is not what I get in browser.What I get in browser is following
[image]
What is the mistake I am probably doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change css to

```
<style type="text/css">

p.float {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0px;
  background: #CCC;
 }

p {
 border: 1px solid red;
}

ul  {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

ul li {
float: left;
    height:40px;
    width:auto;
    background:red;
    margin:2px;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}

ul li a {
display: block;
/* more styles */
}


</style>
```

Comment: what else do u need just play with the styles border and margins to get the exact visualization u have in ur head :-)

Comment: i added some css styles in lopa coding. try this.. Registered User

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps,

```
 ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul li {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
font-size: 18px;
float: left;
width: auto;
margin: 2px;
padding: 6px;
width: 200px;
text-align: center;
background-color: #7B8898;
border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
}

ul li a {
    display: block;
    /* more styles */
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul li a:hover {
    display: block;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #990000;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/suj3j/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS to render the Expected Format for Menu.

```
ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
    }
ul li {
font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 13px;
float: left;
margin: 2px;
padding: 6px;
background:#7B8898;
border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
    }
ul li a {
display: block;
color: #fff;
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration: none;
    }
```